# Javascript Class and extend

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, subclass

I don't quite know how to phrase this so I'll just dive ahead and try to explain it as best as I can.

I don't quite know how to store class properties without using them, or something like that.

If we have a class of **Message** that contains a **method** called *addMessage*.

We want to use this method. inside of a class called *Magic*.

How exactly do we do this?

```
class Message {
    constructor(messageContainer) {
        this.message = messageContainer;
    }

    addMessage(msg) {
        this.message.innerText = msg;
    }
}

class Magic extends Message {
    constructor(magic) {
        super();
        this.magic = magic;
    }

    something() {
        this.addMessage('Some random message');
    }
}
```

We do:

```
const message = new Message(document.getElementById('message-container'))
```

in the code but never use *message* anywhere.

Instead we use *Magic* like so:

```
const magic = new Magic(something)
```

and then:

```
element.addEventListener('click', () => magic.something())
```

This does not work, it does seem logical to why it doesn't, its because message never gets used, but how could we make use of the *addMessage* method inside of *Magic* though?

I've tried a few things but nothing seems to work except for doing `document.getElementById` inside of the `super()`, but that seems to me like it defeats the point of using classes if I can't call it somehow in the code and have it keep the reference to the message container...

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for the help Alex!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Magic` constructor needs to take a `messageContainer` parameter to pass along to the `Message` constructor.

```
class Magic extends Message {
    constructor(messageContainer, magic) {
        super(messageContainer);
        this.magic = magic;
    }

    something() {
        this.addMessage('Some random message');
    }
}

const magic = new Magic(document.getElementById('message-container'), something)
```

If you have lots of parameters and don't want to have list them all when calling `super()`, use an object to hold them instead of using seperate parameters. Each class can use the object properties that pertain to it.

```
class Message {
  constructor(options) {
    this.message = options.messageContainer;
  }

  addMessage(msg) {
    this.message.innerText = msg;
  }
}

class Magic extends Message {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this.magic = options.magic;
  }

  something() {
    this.addMessage('Some random message');
  }
}

magic = new Magic({
  messageContainer: document.getElementById("message-container"),
  magic: something
});
```

Comment: But what if I have too many parameters coming in the *main* class? It was 9 parameters. What I'm trying to achieve is shorten them somehow, but if I still need to pass them on like that, its the same thing. What I was trying now and what helped was passing the initialized Message into Magic as a parameter, this helped because Messages gets 2 parameters where it is used and gets passed into Magic as 1 parameters, so it shortens it. But there has to be a better way, isn't there?

Comment: If you have lots of parameters, use an options object. Then each class can extract the parameters that it wants.

Comment: You are a genius. Just amazing solution, so simple and yet so efficient. Thank you good sir!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inheritance, your use case is composed(`Behavioral design patterns`). Combining 2 objects to work together. here is basic sample to solve this.

```js
class MessageContainer {
  constructor(messageContainer) {
    this.message = messageContainer;
  }
  addMessage(msg) {
    this.message.innerHTML = msg;
  }
}
class Magic {
  constructor(msgContainer) {
    this.container = msgContainer;
  }
  something() {
    this.container.addMessage("Some random message"+ new Date().getTime());
  }
}
const container = new MessageContainer(
  document.getElementById("message-container")
);

const magic = new Magic(container);

document.addEventListener("click", () => {
  magic.something();
});
```

```html
 <div style="height: 100px; color: red;">
        click here
        <br/>
        <span id="message-container"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did to solve this, it works but to be honest I didn't know if this was good practice, but I now understand that it is. Thank you very much for your contribution, I'm sorry I can't mark both as the correct answer because you both brought some very good points to this subject, I hope that we can both be glad about the fact that maybe other people will need this thread and will make use of your solution as well!

Comment: you should not combine each other task. else it will be tightly couple. use delegate patter for you case it make sense to have this. Inheritance is when u want to get parent property. So inheritance is not good here.

Comment: yes I completely agree, after a few solid hours of pushing to use this :D thank you very much for the insight xdeepakv!